# Is it possible to implement boost::thread_specific_ptr via thread_local?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, thread-local-storage

This problem may looks strange. I want to do that because we have some code need to be built on several platforms, but some platform doesn't support thread_local, then use boost::thread_specific_ptr instead. however, it's unpleasing to build boost binary for every platform (x86/x64/arm, debug/release, os, too many).

I wonder if it's possible to imp thread_specific_ptr via thread_local so that we can keep client code more elegant(avoid #ifdef)

I want to have a header file like:

```
#if HAS_THREAD_LOCAL
class thread_specific_ptr
{
    ... // use thread_local to implement
};
#else
using boost::thread_specific_ptr
#endif
```

I can't find the way, maybe you can, thanks.

Comment: In any case you will not avoid if-defs, IMHO best way is take
i.e. 'boost::thread_specific_ptr 'boost::thread_specific_ptr provides a portable mechanism for thread-local storage that works on all compilers supported by Boost.Thread' or if you don't wish to build then just copy-cast boost code (is painful!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to implement `thread_specific_ptr` using `thread_local`. The important part one has to remember is that `thread_local` is a storage specifier and `thread_specific_ptr` is an object. As such it's technically possible to dynamically create and destroy `thread_specific_ptr` objects while you cannot do that with `thread_local` objects. For instance, you cannot put a `thread_local` object as a member of your class.

However, `thread_local` can be used internally by `thread_specific_ptr` to select an internal structure based on the current thread. That structure can contain data for all `thread_specific_ptr`s in the program, and allow dynamic creation and deletion of its elements. One could use a `std::map` for this purpose, for example.

```
thread_local std::map< void*, std::shared_ptr< void > > thread_specific_ptr_data;

template< typename T >
class thread_specific_ptr
{
public:
    T* get() const
    {
        auto it = thread_specific_ptr_data.find(this);
        if (it != thread_specific_ptr_data.end())
            return static_cast< T* >(it->second.get());
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

That, of course, adds some overhead compared to the raw use of `thread_local`, and it can actually be a bit slower than `boost::thread_specific_ptr` on some platforms because `boost::thread_specific_ptr` uses lower-level interfaces than `thread_local`. You would also have to solve the problems `boost::thread_specific_ptr` is facing, like what key to use to look for the value in the map. But this approach can be useful if your goal is to remove the dependency.